# PyQt5 для отображения таблиц базы данных

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyqt5

Нужно сделать приложение для базы данных для курсовой. Я могу вывести все таблицы, используя QTableWidget, но, может быть, есть специальный класс для отображения таблиц из бд? Чтобы была встроенная возможность добавления записей, сортировка и пр.?
Чтобы примерно вот так было: [image: Форма, которую я делала для другой курсовой в Visual Studio и вообще не помню на чем]

Так же буду чень благодарна, если у вас есть примеры, как можно сделать, если специального класса нет.
Пока думаю так: прикручивать +1 строку к каждой таблице вручную, рядом кнопку "Обновить" -- для добавления новых записей. Если возможно прицепить на названия столбцов действия, то там поместить функцию сортировки. Если есть идеи, как это сделать лучше, то тоже буду им благодарна.

БД -- mysql, испоьзую PyQt5, потому что более-менее его знаю:
[image: Вот как сейчас это выглядит]

Comment: Вот вам готовое приложение для курсовой https://github.com/andresnino/PyQt5/tree/master/SIACLE-%20Sistema%20para%20administrar%20clientes%20-%20PARTE%204

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие классы - это `QTableView` и `QSqlTableModel`:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("some_database")
db.setUserName("username")
db.setPassword("password")
db.open()

model = QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("some_table")
model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
model.select()

tableView = QTableView()
tableView.setModel(model)
```

Comment: Сейчас именно так и делаю. Помещу скрин в вопрос. Там нет добавления новой записи как на скриншоте желаемого вида (пустая строка с *). Если других классов или других режимов editStrategy нет, то жаль конечно

Comment: Не пробовали просто добавить `model.insertRows(model.rowCount(), 1)`?

Comment: так вот о том и речь. Значит, нет другого класса, значит, руками всё доделывать нужно? Эх, жаль.